# Man command not installed (fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, man

For some strange reason, when I got my installation of fedora, man command was missing.  I have already install development tools packages - but still no luck.

I checked all the usual suspects: PATH, etc.  No good:

```
> whereis man
man: /usr/share/man
# that's, of course, where documentation goes; not helpful!
```

What is the rpm that gets me man command? (Googling the subject is hard as all kinds of irrelevant results come up.)

Comment: Flagged to move this to unix/linux site - off-topic here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yum install man-db` should give it to you

I'm running Fedora 16 at the moment.

Comment: So it did!  Also, said it needed groff for dependencies, which explains while perldoc was failing to format the output correctly!

Oh boy, is my life better.  Thank you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not installing Fedora again just to answer this question, but on my Amazon Linux AMI (which is RPM based and probably based off Red Hat), it's just a package called `man`.

Does Apropos exist?